# Error during relative import in Python 3.6.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following folder structure

```
my_dir
   __init__.py
   mod1.py
   mod2.py
```

When I tried to import mod1 from mod2 using

```
# mod2.py    
from . import mod1
```

I am getting the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
KeyError: "'__name__' not in globals"
```

I have accomplished this import in a different way. But curious to know what is the reason for this error during this import.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
KeyError: "'__name__' not in globals"`

Comment: Please edit your question and add it there.